# how to use GLib.io_add_watch in backwards-compatible code?

Tags: python, linux, gtk, pygobject

While running some older Python+GTK3 code under Ubuntu 14.04, the following deprecation warnings appeared:

```
PyGIDeprecationWarning: io_add_watch is deprecated; use GLib.io_add_watch instead
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:655: PyGIDeprecationWarning: Calling io_add_watch without priority as second argument is deprecated
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:666: PyGIDeprecationWarning: Calling io_add_watch with priority keyword argument is deprecated, put it as second positional argument
```

This comes from a line where `GObject.io_add_watch()` is called.

From http://www.piware.de/2012/11/pygobject-3-7-2-released/ and http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/GLib_2.0/functions.html?highlight=add_watch#GLib.io_add_watch it looks like the parameter profile for `GLib.io_add_watch()` is different from `GObject.io_add_watch()`. So now I'm wondering:

1. what is the correct way to set an I/O watch on an fd in Python+GTK3? Which function to use, what parameter profile to use?
2. how can I write the code in a way that it is compatible with older systems, eg. Ubuntu 12.04?

Can anyone with experience with this API in old and new systems give some hints?

Comment: oops, this was supposed to be an answer, just a sec...

Answer (score 0):

GLib.io_add_watch() has existed for a long time: It was already there  much before Ubuntu 12.04 was released. So the correct thing is to use that.

I think the function signature is pretty similar, apart from the priority: you should probably use GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT.

Comment: No luck yet... on 14.04 I need to call it like this: GLib.io_add_watch(theFd, prio, GLib.IO_IN, onReadable); but on 12.04 it must be called like this: GLib.io_add_watch(theFd, GLib.IO_IN, onReadable, priority=prio). Using the wrong parameter profile on either system results in exceptions or warnings. Should I seriously add some run-time version check here to find the correct invocation?

Comment: I don't think a run-time version check is so unreasonable given that you're dealing with (unfortunately) changing API.

Comment: @oliver oh, sorry for misleading: I hand't noticed the python wrapper had changed along the way. There's an alternative solution to runtime version checking: name all of the arguments you give. Then the order does not matter.

Comment: jku, thanks for the hint! Looks like the 12.04 bindings don't like named arguments, though ("TypeError: io_add_watch requires at least 3 args") - maybe a simple bug in that version. I've switched to a version check now ("if GObject.pygobject_version < (3, 7, 2)"), which is ugly but should work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A deprecation warning means the functionality in use will be removed in the next major version of PyGObject (which there are currently no plans for). Deprecation warnings only show up in development versions of PyGObject (odd minor version numbers) or when using the -Wd Python command line option to enable deprecation warnings.

If you need to keep compatibility with PyGObject versions prior to 3.7.2, your best bet is to continue using the deprecated version which should work across the entire 3.x series:

```
GObject.io_add_watch(theFd, GLib.IO_IN, onReadable, priority=prio)
```

If this does not work in some version of PyGObject, it is an API break and therefor a bug, please log it here:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=pygobject